# Ajax JSON without correct content type

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get data from ajax response as json. But I am getting error response. I had this problem once, and i manage to solve it by adding `header('Content-type: application/json');` to my php file. But if I do it now it kind of break my code, because i am including the file to another file that has a lot of html code in it and it loads the code in response. Can i get json response without that header somehow ?

```
 $('#catlist').change(function() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
    console.log(opt);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/processproducts.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {opt: opt},
        success: function(options){
            console.log(options);

        },
        error: function(options){
            console.log(options);
            console.log("not working");
        }

    });
    $('#brandlist').attr('disabled', false);

});




<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
//
include '../../core/initialize.php';
/*
include 'includes/head.php';
include 'includes/navigation.php';
include 'includes/functions.php';
*/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product";
$result = $db->query($sql);

if(isset($_REQUEST['submitbtn'])){

    if(isset($_REQUEST['edit'])){
        ?>
        <script> alert("EDIT") </script>

        <?php

        if(!empty($_POST['handleName'])){
            $nameEdVar = $_POST['handleName'];
        } else {
            $nameEdVar = NULL;
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['handleCat'])){
            $catEdVar = $_POST['handleCat'];
        } else {
            $catEdVar = NULL;
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['handleBrand'])){
            $brandEdVar = $_POST['handleBrand'];
        } else {
            $brandEdVar = NULL;
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['handleDesc'])){
            $descEdVar = $_POST['handleDesc'];
        } else {
            $descEdVar = NULL;
        }
        if(!($_FILES['image']['size'] == 0)){ 
            $path = processImg($_REQUEST['edit']);
        } else {
            $path = NULL;
        }
        //$path = NULL;
        $edit_id = (int)$_REQUEST['edit'];
        $sqled = "UPDATE product SET name='$nameEdVar', cat_id='$catEdVar', brand_id='$brandEdVar', image='$path', description='$descEdVar' WHERE product.id_P = $edit_id";
        $db->query($sqled);
        //header('Location: products.php');


    }else{
        if(($_POST['handleName'] =='') || ($_POST['handleCat'] == '') 
            || ($_POST['handleBrand'] == '') || ($_POST['handleDesc'] == '') 
            || ($_FILES['image']['size'] == 0)){ ?>
                 <script> alert('ADD časť niečo nevyplnene'); </script>
            <?php 
        }else{
            ?> <script> alert('ADD časť všetko vyplnene'); </script>
        <?php
            $nameVar = $_POST['handleName'];
            $catVar = $_POST['handleCat'];
            $brandVar = $_POST['handleBrand'];
            $descVar = $_POST['handleDesc'];
            $qVar = 1;

            //$path = "https://localhost/shop/imgs/31.jpg";

            $sql = "SELECT MAX(id_p) FROM product";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($maxid);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $path = processImg(++$maxid);
            $stmt->close();

            $sql = "INSERT INTO product (id_p, name, cat_id, brand_id, image, description, quantity) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $nullvar = NULL, $nameVar, $catVar, $brandVar, $path, $descVar, $qVar);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            //header('Location: products.php');

        }
    }

}
//Delete Product
if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])){
    $delete_id = (int)$_GET['delete'];
    $sqldel = "DELETE FROM product WHERE product.id_p = $delete_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sqldel);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    header('Location: products.php');
}


if(isset($_REQUEST['edit'])){
    echo "
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#addBox').modal('show');
            })
        </script>";
}



$sqlcat = "SELECT * FROM category";
$stmtcat = $db->prepare($sqlcat);
$stmtcat->execute();
$stmtcat->bind_result($cat_id, $type);
$stmtcat->store_result();
$cat = array();
while($stmtcat->fetch()){
    $cat[$cat_id] = array();
    $cat[$cat_id]["type"] = $type;
}
$stmtcat->close();

$sqlbrand = "SELECT * FROM brand";
$stmtbrand = $db->prepare($sqlbrand);
$stmtbrand->execute();
$stmtbrand->bind_result($brand_id, $name);
$stmtbrand->store_result();
$brand = array();
while($stmtbrand->fetch()){
    $brand[$brand_id] = array();
    $brand[$brand_id]["name"] = $name;
}
$stmtbrand->close();


if(isset($_REQUEST['submitcategory'])){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO category (cat_id, type) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cat_id = cat_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $cat_id = NULL, $_REQUEST['category']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();


    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value){if($key != "category" && $value != "Submit"){
        if($value == ""){
            exit();
        }
        var_dump($value);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO brand(brand_id, NAME) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE brand_id = brand_id";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $brand_id = NULL, $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $sql = "SELECT brand_id, cat_id FROM brand,category WHERE brand.name= ? AND category.type = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $value, $_REQUEST['category']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($brand_id, $cat_id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO brand_category(brand_id, cat_id) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE brand_id = brand_id";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $brand_id, $cat_id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}
}elseif(isset($_REQUEST['submitbrand'])){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO brand (brand_id, name) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE brand_id = brand_id";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('is', $brand_id = NULL, $_REQUEST['brand']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    foreach ($_REQUEST as $key=>$value){if($key != "brand" && $value != "Submit"){
        if($value == ""){
            exit();
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO category (cat_id, type) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cat_id = cat_id";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $cat_id = NULL, $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        $sql = "SELECT brand_id, cat_id FROM brand,category WHERE brand.name= ? AND category.type = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_REQUEST['brand'], $value);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($brand_id, $cat_id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();

        $sql = "INSERT INTO brand_category(brand_id, cat_id) VALUES(?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE brand_id = brand_id";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $brand_id, $cat_id );
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

    }
}
}

$sql = "SELECT brand.name, brand.brand_id FROM brand JOIN brand_category ON brand_category.brand_id = brand.brand_id WHERE brand_category.cat_id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['opt']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($name, $brand_id);
$stmt->store_result();
$options = array();
echo $name;
echo $brand_id;
while($stmt->fetch()){
    $options[$brand_id] = array();
    $options[$brand_id]["name"] = $name;
}
//header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($options);

$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: what error you get it?

Comment: Well, it just go in ajax to `error: function(options)` instead of `success: function()`

Comment: try storing all the html code in a variable and then json_encode that variable.

Comment: can you share some of `processproducts.php` 's code?

Comment: Yea but i don't want that html code, i just need to get one array.

Comment: @rtom upload your php code as well.

Comment: It's just code for database work

Comment: /then remove all the html code

Comment: ajax works on the fact that it will take all the html and javascript codes, if it is present.

Comment: I edited OP... there isn't html in this file, but i am including it to another file, and it gets all the html from that file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123680/discussion-between-botjr-and-rtom).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from your ajax call:

```
dataType: "json"
```

and change the line

```
success: function(options){
   var data = JSON.parse(options);   // convert the json to js array and use it       
}
```

Try this, it will work

Comment: I get following error `sample.js:122 Uncaught TypeError: JSON.response is not a function`

Comment: Please check the updated code. Its JSON.parse(). Sorry for the mistake :(

Comment: `VM1037:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0`  First word in the object is Windows so that W problably belongs to it.

Comment: There is some character that breaks your json. Please check it by printr=_r($array) the array.

Comment: I managed to solved it by creating a new file just for the ajax. I have kind of bad structure of my code and it didn't come to my mind that i could solve it simply as that. But thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by creating file just for ajax call.